# Neo4j spatial 0.14-neo4j-2.2.3 geotools dependency issue

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I am trying to use neo4j-spatial-0.14-neo4j-2.2.3 with neo4j 2.2.5 and I am facing the following issue while creating a SpatialDatabaseService.

Here is the stack trace. Obviously it looks like a version compatibility issue.

The issue seems to be with the gt-metadata jar. I am not including this directly in my POM. Its a dependency added through neo4j-spatial.

Can any expert suggest the compatible version of neo4j-spatial.

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.geotools.metadata.iso.citation.ContactImpl.getOnlineResource()Lorg/opengis/metadata/citation/OnlineResource;
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.geotools.metadata.PropertyAccessor.get(PropertyAccessor.java:474) ~[gt-metadata-9.2.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.metadata.PropertyAccessor.hashCode(PropertyAccessor.java:789) ~[gt-metadata-9.2.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.metadata.MetadataStandard.hashCode(MetadataStandard.java:323) ~[gt-metadata-9.2.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.metadata.AbstractMetadata.hashCode(AbstractMetadata.java:215) ~[gt-metadata-9.2.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.metadata.PropertyAccessor.hashCode(PropertyAccessor.java:791) ~[gt-metadata-9.2.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.metadata.MetadataStandard.hashCode(MetadataStandard.java:323) ~[gt-metadata-9.2.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.metadata.AbstractMetadata.hashCode(AbstractMetadata.java:215) ~[gt-metadata-9.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:362) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:492) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:217) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.geotools.util.CheckedHashSet.add(CheckedHashSet.java:216) ~[gt-metadata-9.2.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.metadata.iso.citation.CitationImpl.<init>(CitationImpl.java:177) ~[gt-metadata-9.2.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.metadata.iso.citation.Citations.<clinit>(Citations.java:86) ~[gt-metadata-9.2.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.datum.DefaultGeodeticDatum.<clinit>(DefaultGeodeticDatum.java:70) ~[gt-referencing-9.2.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS.<clinit>(DefaultGeographicCRS.java:97) ~[gt-referencing-9.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.gis.spatial.SpatialDatabaseService.<clinit>(SpatialDatabaseService.java:444) ~[neo4j-spatial-0.14-neo4j-2.2.3.jar:na]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Version of Neo4j and Neo4j Spatial must be the same.

Neo4j Spatial for Neo4j 2.2.5 - https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/m2/tree/master/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-spatial/0.14-neo4j-2.2.5

Comment: I tried using Neo4j spatial 0.14-neo4j-2.2.5. Still seeing the same issue. Could this be because of the geotools jars?